# RabbitMQ for Coveo stopped

Tags: sitecore, coveo

I installed "Coveo Enterprise Search 7.0 " and "Coveo Search API " Locally on my PC "which use Window 7 OS" from link text

When I tried to start "RabbitMQ for Coveo" it always stop and log the below error in the Event views

> RabbitMQ for Coveo: Erlang machine voluntarily stopped. The service is
>   not restarted as OnFail is set to ignore.

I tried to change the log in user for the service which is by default "Local System Account" to my domain user and the same error logged

Comment: https://answers.coveo.com/questions/5678/rabbitmq-for-coveo-stopped please check this link.

Comment: I am the person that put this question and try all the suggestions without any luck

Comment: Hi @DuaaAbuGharbieh, did you check if other application might be using the RabbitMQ's default port? If not can you click on Start button, type CMD and right click, then **Run as Administrator** and type `netstat -ab` ? Please share with us the output of the command.